# how to create a vector map of some locations

Tags: google-maps, maps, vector-graphics

I want to mark some locations in a vector map. And would like to save the map in pdf format with separate layers.I tried arcgis but the map is online cannot export it to a file. can i know what is the common and standerd way of representing data  using a vecotr map

Answer (score 0):

Try this vector maps first, they have free versions, it can be useful:[http://vectormap.info/free-maps-for-all-designers-and-mappers][1] it could be easier for you too